# gitignore won't ignore my .settings/ directory (created by eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, git, gitignore

git status:

```
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .settings/
```

I've tried the following variations on my .gitignore file and nothing seems to work:

```
.settings/

*settings*

*.settings/

.settings/*
```

I've never had this much trouble with `.gitignore`, it usually just works. I must be doing something real dumb.

NOTE: My `.gitignore` file has more in it than just that one line (all the other lines works correctly).

Comment: .settings/* works for me. wher eis located your gitignorefile compared to the .settings directory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My .gitignore file has a leading forward slash before .settings:

```
/.settings
```

where you don't have that slash.  Try adding the slash

Comment: the leading slash will ensure that only the `.settings` folder in the root directory (relative to the `.gitignore` file) is ignored (as opposed to e.g. `foo/.settings`)

Comment: @umläute But the .settings is always in the root directory.  The question was specifically about the .settings folder in an Eclipse project.  This solution addresses the question.

Comment: @umläute Read the question.  The question specifically asks how to gitignore the .settings directory.  I answered that specific question.  If the OP wants to know how to gitignore other directories then the OP should modify the question.

Comment: Wouldn't just `.settings` in gitignore work for all `.settings` folders?

Answer (score 13):

I thought I had the same problem. Turns out, the reason I kept seeing .settings/ in **git status** was because someone else already committed .settings/ to the repo. So, .settings/ kept showing up under the *Changes not staged for commit* files list because my IDE touched/changed this directory.

You want .settings/ to stay invisible to git so remove it from tracking. Then, when you make a change that touches this directory, you won't see it under the Untracked files list because you added it to the .gitignore file. Whoever committed .settings/ in the 1st place also won't see it as eligible for commit either because they updated their .gitignore file with your update to ignore .settings/ folder.

Comment: how do I remove a folder from tracking?

Comment: @AuxiliaryJoel `git rm -r --cached <folder>/`

Answer (score 7):

/**/.settings/

worked to ignore the .settings folders below the root.

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was to move `.settings/` to the end of the `.gitignore` file. Initially I was just making it the first line of the `.gitignore` file. Not sure why that matters. Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: No clear explanation for what you've observed. But, FWIW, this has worked fine for me: `/.settings` -- up near the top of the file, even...

Comment: Confirmed. I already had a `*` line in my `.gitignore` file and yet my `/documents/` directory (exact line) wasn’t ignored. When I moved my explicit (and seemingly redundant) `/documents/` line after my `!*/` line, it worked. There are a lot of Git repos in that directory. Maybe that’s confusing for Git.